# Change All URLs Structure using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I search here and try all solutions but no one solution worked for me.

In my Public_html folder of my domain root, I have installed WordPress.  Now, In directory of Public_html, I create a sub-directory and named it app.  After that i upload a PHP Script but my script is not give me complete path.  And my URLs not load CSS,JS,and images files from app sub-directory.

These are my site URLs links.

```
Main Page
http://example.com
http://example.com/index.php

Single Video Pages
http://example.com/watch/tlb2UbRcuME
http://example.com/watch/ps2lXZegtBM
http://example.com/watch/D7cJn2Sy6FU

Search Pages
http://example.com/search/Learn+PHP
http://example.com/search/New+VEVO
http://example.com/search/New+songs

Images and Images folder Paths
http://example.com/img/logo.png
http://example.com/imgages/php.png

JavaScripts and CSS folder Paths
http://example.com/js/player.js
http://example.com/js/mini.js
http://example.com/css/style.css
http://example.com/css/player.css

Other Single Pages
http://example.com/contact
http://example.com/privacy
http://example.com/dmca
```

(1) Now, I want to change the directory or folder.

I want to access all above links with APP sub-directory or sub-folder.
I mean i want to add sub-directory named APP after domain URL.

I want to add directory or folder name into the URLs Links after domain.
The directory name is APP or app

for examples...I want above all URLs Links and all other links should be
access like these...

```
Main Page
http://example.com/app
http://example.com/app/index.php

Single Video Pages
http://example.com/app/watch/tlb2UbRcuME
http://example.com/app/watch/ps2lXZegtBM
http://example.com/app/watch/D7cJn2Sy6FU

Search Pages
http://example.com/app/search/Learn+PHP
http://example.com/app/search/New+VEVO
http://example.com/app/search/New+songs

Images and Images folder Paths
http://example.com/app/img/logo.png
http://example.com/app/imgages/php.png

JavaScripts and CSS folder Paths
http://example.com/app/js/player.js
http://example.com/app/js/mini.js
http://example.com/app/css/style.css
http://example.com/app/css/player.css

Other Single Pages
http://example.com/app/contact
http://example.com/app/privacy
http://example.com/app/dmca
```

(2) I also want to access all HTTP WWW URLs
with HTTPS Non-WWW URLs.

for Example :

```
http://www.example.com/app/dmca
```

into

```
https://example.com/app/dmca
```

above and all other URLs with HTTPS Non-WWW URLs.

What .htaccess file code will be for above situation.
Is there any solution  or suggestion for above problem.

That is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*?)/page/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1&token=$2
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*?)/page/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1&token=$2
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^watch/(.+)$ /watch.php?id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)$ /index.php?q=&page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(cache/|submit\.php|head\.php|head_mobile\.php|foot\.php|foot_mobile\.php|includes\.php|config\.php) - [F,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dmca$ /dmca.php
RewriteRule ^privacy$ /privacy.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure, `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` enabled trough `httpd.conf` then you can use:

To do this `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

http://example.com/index.php to http://example.com/app/index.php

```
RewriteRule ^$ /app [L]
```

This one does not display `/app/` on the url bar. If you also want to show `/app/` folder on the url, you can use this option:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /app [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you check httpd.conf you need to make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess is enabled otherwise .htacess file on your main folder does not have any effect

Comment: mod_rewrite and .htacess is enabled

Comment: That's not worked for me !
in my Public_html folder of my domain root, I have installed wordpress.

Now, In directory of Public_html, I create a sub-directory and named it app

After that i upload a PHP Script but my script is not give me complete path.
And my URLs not load CSS,JS,and images files from app sub-directory.
I want to load all files like above.

Comment: Interesting is both of them are not working ? or only rewrite rule /app ? because first one has no relation with subfolders etc. and have to work if it is not you have some other server issue. I also suggest make sure you are refreshing your browser cache while your reloading the page.

Comment: https rule worked but rewrite rule for folder of /app did not worked.

Please check above my .htaccess file i add in my question after edit it.